# Popup menu in toolbar MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am created toolbar in MFC, now I am trying to add pop-up menu on one of button. Can anyone please give me some hint for doing this.

Infact I am not getting how to show the down arrow which used to attached with the toolbar buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see this [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ke6s1fc(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ke6s1fc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

for creating the pop-up menu I have gone through overriding this function.

```
afx_msg int OnCreateControl(LPCREATECONTROLSTRUCT lpCreateControl);
```